# Ranking in Google for New Sites

Tags: seo, google, google-search

I have a 3-months old site. I have been doing decent SEO for it.

I have just 1 or 0 people visiting the site from Google and its concerning me. Is there some wait period before sites start to rank?

In case anyone wants to check the backlink profile, the site problemio dot com (didn't want to seem spammy by posting the actual url)

Answer (score 1):

Well you should be getting some Traffic from Google because 3 months is a long time and I gained more than 10 visits via Google in just 15-30 days.
So please look out what is wrong use some Google webmaster tools and [Bing webmaster tools.](http://www.bing.com/toolbox/webmaster)

Check whether you done these things or not

1. Did you submit XML sitemap to google and Bing?
2. Is you theme safe and clean(Xhtml validated)?
3. Do you use many flash, PDF and images instead of contents?
4. Do you use H tags in your content?
5. Is your robots.txt file is correctly configured?

Most important things are Content you need to have good contents in order to showup on results.

Answer (score 0):

You're site is indexed in google. 3 month is not really enough.

Google crawlers put weight on the link in the long run.
don't be so sensitive. When I ran my site a year ago, I was the same as you are now.

just be patient and my recommendation is to use Google webmaster tools to analyze your traffic and get more trust from google.

Answer (score 0):

Its been 3 months & you have less traffic as you mentioned that only 0 or 1 visitors. I would recommend you to add more content in your website and so proper onpage. Spend one hou